# WPF Ribbon: full re-templating support

Tags: wpf, styles, ribbon

does exist any WPF ribbon control (commercial or not) that support full re-templating? Generally they have a number of built-in graphic themes but do not allow graphic redesign from scratch. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even IF you would find one - there is a reason they do not allow full redesign, and that is that the Ribbon is legally protected by microsoft and you are only allowed to change the behavior that far. If you install, for example, the Ribbon support from Infragistics, you have to accept a separate license with Microsoft limiting what you can do.

So, the full styling support is missing for a good legal reason. Even a good technical one - I can understand MS putting some screws on developers to make sure Ribbon applications do behave "correctly" across applications.

Answer (score 0):

I find [Teleriks](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/ribbonbar.aspx) ribbon control was pretty good. I am not sure if it supports full re-templating although it does say it allows flexible styling?

I have also used [Actipro's](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/dotnet/wpf/ribbon/default.aspx) ribbon control in the past but found it a bit tedious.